# Problem in calculating monthly pixel area chart in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geemap

I'm trying to get weekly and monthly pixel area using the same technique which is used in daily bases. But I'm facing the error problem when I map area function on monthly images. Here is the problematic,

```js
var mod = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1')  
.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover')

var year = 2012
var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1)
var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'year')
var yearFiltered = mod
  .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate))

// print(yearFiltered)

// Create a list of months
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12)

// Write a function that takes a month number
// and returns a monthly image
var createMonthlyImage = function(month) {
  var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, 1)
  var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'month')
  var monthFiltered = yearFiltered
    .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate))
  // Calculate total precipitation
  var total = monthFiltered.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
  return total.set({
    'system:time_start': startDate.millis(),
    'system:time_end': endDate.millis(),
    'year': year,
    'month': month})
}

// map() the function on the list  of months
// This creates a list with images for each month in the list
var monthlyImages = months.map(createMonthlyImage)
// Create an imagecollection
var monthlyCollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(monthlyImages)

print(monthlyCollection)

var monthly = monthlyCollection.map(function(snowCover) {
  var snowArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6)
    .updateMask(snowCover.gte(1))
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: AOI,
      scale: 500,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    })
  return ee.Feature(null, snowArea)
})

// Create a chart of monthly rainfall for a location
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: monthly,
  region: AOI,
}).setOptions({
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
      title: 'Monthly Area',
      vAxis: {title: 'Area (km)'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Month', gridlines: {count: 12}}
})
print(chart)
```

Also, the total monthly pixel area is not accurate when we print monthly.
The full script is given here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ea276c995ac61ba6c678b71d64c309e9

Comment: Could you be more specific as to where the problem is? I think the output is being generated correctly (`print(monthly)`).

Comment: I want to generate chart but its showing collection error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to make a chart for an image (`ui.Chart.image.series`) using a FeatureCollection (`monthly`). Thus, you need to use the corresponding function to create a chart from a FeatureCollection (`ui.Chart.feature.byFeature`).

```
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: monthly,
}).setOptions({
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
      title: 'Monthly Area',
      vAxis: {title: 'Area (km)'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Month', gridlines: {count: 12}}
})
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I have changed my script to find first pixel area and then get monthly values on chart but its showing the band is not found. can you help this? here is script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/af8a3e4d14d6e0b4686166423c503f0e